# Bigcartel - Neat theme removing picture grid theme slider

Tags: themes, neat, bigcartel

I am currently working on customizing the welcome page for my Bigcartel site.

I am using the Neat theme and would like to remove the grid filter that appears over the slideshow [image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Yd6s.png) to appear clean [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2gXb.png)

I was wondering if it's possible in Big Cartel and what was the process to follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the grid, you'll need to drop the following code into the bottom of the CSS section in your Customize Design area:

```
.slideshow div.featured_holder {
  background: none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

add this in your css

`.slideshow .featured_holder {
   background-image:none
}`